# toggling a div's height with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle a divs height, but when I do it only clicks once on and once off.  Is there anyway to get it to toggle no matter how many times I click?  Thanks!  Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#block1').click(function () {
        toggle = document.getElementById('block1').style.height;
        if (toggle <= 30) {
            $("#block1").css('height', '200px');
        } else $("#block1").css('height', '30px');
    });
});
```

Comment: put the height in a class and use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('block1').style.height` returns `30px`.

`'30px' <= 30` returns `false`, so the height keeps getting set to `30px`.

You could use `.height()`, which returns a number, but I'd suggest using a class and toggling:

http://jsfiddle.net/TQs6h/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#block1').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('tall');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using jQuery I will suggest you to use [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method it will return Integer value you can compare instead of String value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#block1').click(function () {
        var toggle = $( this ).height();
        if (toggle <= 30) {
            $( this ).css('height', '200px');
        } else $( this ).css('height', '30px');
    });
});
```

Or you can use `parseInt` function:

```
var toggle = parseInt( document.getElementById('block1').style.height, 10) ;
```

See jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LYrZ2/)